# Usage of "optimize"

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Say I want to maximize the production of corn by controlling factors X, Y, Z. In english, do I say 1) I want to optimize corn yield/production (optimal response) OR 2) I want to optimize the level of X,Y,Z to maximize corn yield (optimal factors)? Please advise, thank you.

Comment: If you want to ***maximize*** production, the implication is you want production to be as high as possible, regardless of financial, sociological, etc. ramifications (consider Nick Bostrom,'s [***paperclip maximizer***](https://wiki.lesswrong.com/wiki/Paperclip_maximizer) as the canonical thought experiment showing how an artificial general intelligence might go seriously wrong). But if you want to ***optimize*** production, the implication is you want to do it in the best possible way (probably with some sensible upper limit! :)

Comment: You can't maximize a process, but you can optimize it. Numbers can be optimized, maximized, minimized, etc. Optimize and maximize are not the same. "Optimizing" your weight would NOT be maximizing it, or minimizing it. I believe you want to set/tune/adjust/etc X, Y, and Z to maximize corn yield. The correct set/tune/adjust/etc there depends on what X, Y and Z are.

Answer (score 1):

Solving an optimization problem

```
max/min corn(X,Y,Z)
(X,Y,Z) in A,
```

fully, consists in finding two things:

1. Finding the max/min possible value that the function `corn` can attain under the restriction that `(X,Y,Z)` is in `A`.
2. Finding all the points of `A` for which that maximum/minimum is attained.

Note that once you have the latter, then the optimal values can be obtained by evaluating the objective function. If, on the other hand, you have the optimal values, then the set of optimizing points can be found by solving an equation (inverting the objective function).

In this sense, when you have one, you can produce the other. The problem is essentially solved.

This is why both options, (1) and (2), are used to refer to solving the same problem. One optimizes both the values of the objective function and the values of the variables.

Comment: This answer is an attempt to solve the mathematical problem presented in the question rather than solving the English language problem that was intended.

Comment: @KillingTime You clearly have no idea what this answer is saying. This answer explains why *optimize* refers to both finding optimal values of the objective function and finding optimizing points for the parameters. It explains why finding either of them can be considered as the full problem being solved. This explains why the language refers to the optimization problem as either of the two parts of the full solution.